# Why is my subdataset blank when I run report from Java code?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I created a table design using Jaspersoft Studio. When I am using this jrxml in Java no table is displayed

I am using Jaspersoft Studio as a plugin in Eclipse to generate jrxml. While previewing the table gets displayed in JSS, but when I am using Java code to export it into pdf/xls/docx its not getting loaded. Empty file without any data.

This is my JRXML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_Landscape" pageWidth="802" pageHeight="555" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="f391983e-5ad3-4a64-b310-fc7f3426e3f0">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Oracle"/>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()%2==0)]]></conditionExpression>
            <style backcolor="#E3F1FF"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="table" uuid="9fa2cf87-1e9b-4673-a13c-55f4b337d4db">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Oracle"/>
        <queryString language="SQL">
            <![CDATA[select * from CODE]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="MOBILE" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="COMPANY_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="SITE_ID" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="SITE_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="IN_TIME" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="OUT_TIME" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="CREATE_ON" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[select * from CODE]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="MOBILE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="COMPANY_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SITE_ID" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SITE_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="IN_TIME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="OUT_TIME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="CREATE_ON" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <title>
        <band height="50" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="100" height="30" forecolor="#007BFF" uuid="46c45769-ac34-41af-bdb4-c45729f333b9"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Call Logs]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a">
                <reportElement x="450" y="20" width="330" height="30" forecolor="#007BFF" uuid="7a3c6c9d-bf5b-487d-8e13-720ecda75b61"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Report Generated on:  "+new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="243" splitType="Stretch">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT} != 0]]></printWhenExpression>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="41" y="24" width="720" height="200" uuid="24f1ba3d-2de9-4a32-9f9f-75d592f91359">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT} == 1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="table" uuid="f76f4c9b-3345-4d0e-8cad-dd8a75913665">
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="104" uuid="229daaed-80a6-42c5-9ade-2f0c75d1963e">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="104" height="30" uuid="cfa9503a-bbfe-41fb-96a6-46c633a691fc"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[NAME]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="104" height="30" uuid="d0395260-510c-44dd-88c0-3c5ab97a6f65"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="101" uuid="94785e2c-8fa8-4402-8506-4f234bf064bd">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="101" height="30" uuid="03b5ef55-113a-485c-9d09-519dcc9d6152"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[MOBILE]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="101" height="30" uuid="dba6ea8d-23d1-4af3-bf64-475a5266b85f"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{MOBILE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="101" uuid="8151f7e4-e41b-430b-8730-b5499a6d5d1f">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="101" height="30" uuid="2321d1fa-4e3f-4d3f-8727-bae188bafd7b"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[COMPANY_NAME]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="101" height="30" uuid="d9d2d45e-98cc-4f52-8b3d-4d2829d5df34"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{COMPANY_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="101" uuid="1c6cc322-6497-437a-8945-c1c3f08287b0">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="101" height="30" uuid="2720a693-f022-4498-93e3-4d0aa7b37982"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[SITE_NAME]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="101" height="30" uuid="c34d16ae-244f-4b73-8e54-71655a5fc231"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SITE_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="105" uuid="7b35eec3-38c2-4b76-aa58-d7cb1dc0925c">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="105" height="30" uuid="29e866cb-fecc-4854-abdb-4e131883b68e"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[IN_TIME]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="105" height="30" uuid="d3b432d0-95e4-4d4a-b6a8-4984f3c95164"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{IN_TIME}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="104" uuid="ba443c16-d86f-483c-9e79-035cfc42ce40">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="104" height="30" uuid="a6d98a0b-d280-475a-8b7e-7e88778c5dcd"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[OUT_TIME]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="104" height="30" uuid="9fa9cd8c-da08-4871-9cb1-6655d0a14e34"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{OUT_TIME}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="104" uuid="3aac9567-fd44-4954-8542-60806e43e960">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="104" height="30" uuid="81d7af3f-bfd5-4bda-8c4c-645d44c718b9"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[CREATE_ON]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="104" height="30" uuid="502689db-da95-4dba-bdd9-fc066be71100"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CREATE_ON}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

And this is my Java code:

```
public class PDFReportGenerator {
    public static String ACTUAL_REPORT_PATH = "E:\\path\\Blank_A4_Landscape.jrxml";
    public static String PDF_PATH = "E:\\path\\Blank_A4_Landscape.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JRException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        generateReport();
    }

    static void generateReport() {
        Connection conn = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        JasperReport jasperReport = null;
        JasperPrint print = null;
        String query ="SELECT * FROM CODE";
        try {   
            if(conn==null) {
                try {
                    conn= OracleConnection.getConnection();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }   
        CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall(query);
        rs=cstmt.executeQuery();
        JRResultSetDataSource resultSetDataSource = new JRResultSetDataSource(rs);      
        jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(ACTUAL_REPORT_PATH);
        Map <String, Object> parameters = new HashMap <String, Object>();
        print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, resultSetDataSource);
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, PDF_PATH);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your `subDataset` executes a query and you are passing a database connection to it.

```
<connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
```

In java you need to pass this connection to `fillReport` instead of your `JRResultSetDataSource`

```
print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,parameters, conn);
```

Another solution to keep the `JRResultSetDataSource` as main datasource would be to create another datasource for the subreport and pass this as a parameter modifying the `datasetRun` expression in jrxml accordingly, hence using this datasource instead of report connection.

---

To clarify, it works in IDE because in IDE you are selecting the connection before you run the report, `<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Oracle"/>`, but these settings are not valid/loaded when running directly from java.

Comment: and also i need to know, how to pass result set into the reports,instead of connection.

Comment: @alexander I would pass the connection, if it works in IDE it would work also in java, If you like to use JRResultSetDataSource  as state in answer you need to create another one for the sub table and pass it in parameters. Then edit datasource expression to use this parameter (datasource) instead of the connection.

Comment: thanks for the reply. But i have no idea how to do it. pls share a code snippet for the above solution

Comment: @alexander 1. Create the datsource in java, 2 Pass in the parameters map, 3 create the parameter with the correct class in jrxml, 4 pass it to the datasetRun (datasource expression). If there is some specific step you are having trouble with let me know.

Comment: I need to pass result set from java to jasper report instead of (query present in report).  How to do it.

I created oracle datasource in java. I don't know how to pass in parameter map.. and other followed steps pls help @Petter

Comment: @alexander parameters.put("mykey", mydatasource), then in jrxml add the parameters if still in doubt use Google "Java, How to pass parameters to Jasper report" There should be tons of example of this

Comment: anyone please help me!