# How can I get the first record of the table by using the same data-source for the main report and table in Jasper reports?

Tags: jasper-reports

According to my design requirement, I am trying to create a simple Jasper report( using Jasper-soft Studio in 6.12 version) with Table in which the main report and table should be populated by java code using JRResultSetDataSource object with same query execution or data-source and also calculating the record count in page header, of the number of rows fetched in the table from the database.

But the problem is that- Either only table is getting  populated through the data Source or only main report is getting populated or while providing same data-source to both main report and table then the first record of the table is missing because the record pointer in the data source is incremented as the data-source is passed from main report to table. Nor am I able to clone the data source to provide a copy of the data-source to the table as it is not supported for JRResultSetDataSource.

I want to use the same data-source to populate the table and to populate text fields present in the main report.

Java code-

```
 Connection con;
 Statement stmt;
 ResultSet rs;

 try {
      Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
      con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/jasperexamples", "postgres", "password");
       stmt=con.createStatement();
       String query= "select * from product";
       rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
            
       JRResultSetDataSource rsdt = new JRResultSetDataSource(rs);

       String jasperReport = "/home/sakshi/JaspersoftWorkspace/MyReports/JasperProduct.jasper";
       JasperPrint jp1 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, new HashMap<String, Object>(),rsdt);

        JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(jp1);
        jv.setVisible(true);
        con.close();
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Jrxml code-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.12.2.final using JasperReports Library version 6.12.2-75c5e90a222ab406e416cbf590a5397028a52de3  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="JasperProduct" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="0d6d7195-8cff-4512-be5d-258e505e6836">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="Dataset1" uuid="0dc50125-a9d2-458b-82aa-27bfa253f3e9">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="prouductname" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="productprize" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="company" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="prouductname" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="productprize" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="company" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="802" height="30" uuid="463c4bc3-254d-4c78-a35e-0096dc006165"/>
                <box leftPadding="5"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="24"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Product Report]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="55" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="5" y="17" width="110" height="30" uuid="836aa66c-e052-4ca1-ac75-feb821efa866"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Report Count]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                <reportElement x="125" y="17" width="100" height="30" uuid="500a4853-c045-4897-a007-6e77598a31c7"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="199" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="34" width="802" height="126" uuid="dc722ea3-7c31-439b-996c-bb3892426aea">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table_TH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table_CH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table_TD"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.autoresize.proportional" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset1" uuid="2c3773b9-e3a5-4046-a9d7-825487945fbb">
                        <datasetParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:columnGroup width="802" uuid="35fb663c-fc50-45f9-8715-575fe5aa27f4">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Columns [4]"/>
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="802" height="30" uuid="9cdc6108-4308-449a-9995-182837f26b4d"/>
                                <box leftPadding="3"/>
                                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="18"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Product Details]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:columnGroup width="802" uuid="2282f969-105d-4cf7-9714-ce0eef6e7a2a">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Columns [4]"/>
                            <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                                <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="802" height="30" uuid="4aa3d9f1-22dd-44bb-b002-b1fc83349c66"/>
                                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                        <font size="13"/>
                                    </textElement>
                                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                </textField>
                            </jr:tableFooter>
                            <jr:column width="200" uuid="88208a30-4a0d-4a22-8558-c9347efcab95">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column1"/>
                                <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                                    <staticText>
                                        <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="30" uuid="c7b0da69-05cb-4e00-b215-501476c06697"/>
                                        <box leftPadding="3"/>
                                        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                            <font size="12" isBold="true" isItalic="false"/>
                                        </textElement>
                                        <text><![CDATA[Id]]></text>
                                    </staticText>
                                </jr:columnHeader>
                                <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                                    <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="30" uuid="69c964ef-8985-4b28-adf2-eb89663ffa3c"/>
                                        <box leftPadding="3"/>
                                        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                            <font size="12"/>
                                        </textElement>
                                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                    </textField>
                                </jr:detailCell>
                            </jr:column>
                            <jr:column width="190" uuid="26ed996c-7261-48e1-bfdd-5492a313bee9">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column2"/>
                                <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                                    <staticText>
                                        <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="190" height="30" uuid="294980bc-20b3-472e-999f-5be40daacf01"/>
                                        <box leftPadding="3"/>
                                        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                            <font size="12" isBold="true" isItalic="false"/>
                                        </textElement>
                                        <text><![CDATA[Product Name]]></text>
                                    </staticText>
                                </jr:columnHeader>
                                <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                                    <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="190" height="30" uuid="30e24e73-2357-40a9-ba78-a8dff9938ab9"/>
                                        <box leftPadding="3"/>
                                        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                            <font size="12"/>
                                        </textElement>
                                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{prouductname}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                    </textField>
                                </jr:detailCell>
                            </jr:column>
                            <jr:column width="220" uuid="efd0925b-65d3-438e-950c-95fefc05998e">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column3"/>
                                <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                                    <staticText>
                                        <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="220" height="30" uuid="1480c534-2f5f-4cc7-96be-e275415b8cd0"/>
                                        <box leftPadding="3"/>
                                        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                            <font size="12" isBold="true" isItalic="false"/>
                                        </textElement>
                                        <text><![CDATA[Product Prize]]></text>
                                    </staticText>
                                </jr:columnHeader>
                                <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                                    <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="220" height="30" uuid="2df7f400-4845-4ebe-a874-c3ae91ccba2e"/>
                                        <box leftPadding="3"/>
                                        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                            <font size="12"/>
                                        </textElement>
                                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{productprize}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                    </textField>
                                </jr:detailCell>
                            </jr:column>
                            <jr:column width="192" uuid="dfd8aead-b732-4300-8a47-29b0a6b7605b">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column4"/>
                                <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                                    <staticText>
                                        <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="192" height="30" uuid="7fac6d69-f0eb-4ff2-82de-152872d9930d"/>
                                        <box leftPadding="3"/>
                                        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                            <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                                        </textElement>
                                        <text><![CDATA[Company]]></text>
                                    </staticText>
                                </jr:columnHeader>
                                <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                                    <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="192" height="30" uuid="701bebcf-d200-4cf8-bd88-37f4578be852"/>
                                        <box leftPadding="3"/>
                                        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                            <font size="12"/>
                                        </textElement>
                                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{company}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                    </textField>
                                </jr:detailCell>
                            </jr:column>
                        </jr:columnGroup>
                    </jr:columnGroup>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="62">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="160" height="30" uuid="dca10f20-8fa6-4e1b-8d48-16b549783ac6"/>
                <box leftPadding="3">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="13" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Company Name: ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                <reportElement x="160" y="20" width="642" height="30" uuid="2e69e42c-7588-429b-a0dc-42042e24bd61"/>
                <box leftPadding="3">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="13"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{company}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

I have seen different approaches-

- add a first empty row to the datasource before passing it to the
  report.
- passing two data sources- one to table and one to main
  report.(But both work on the same datasource so it reduces the
  performance).

But I don't think these approaches are good.

And also referred to different references but they didn't work according to my design requirement-

- [Why is my subdataset blank when I run report from Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58078369/why-is-my-subdataset-blank-when-i-run-report-from-java-)
- http://zetcode.com/articles/jaspertable/
- http://junaedhalim.blogspot.com/2009/12/creating-jasperreport-with-subreports.html
- https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/540719/resolved-table-report-missing-1st-tablemodel-row
- https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/817326/table-not-displaying-any-values
- [Jasper Reports how to set data from JRResultSetDataSource into Table component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43045519/jasper-reports-how-to-set-data-from-jrresultsetdatasource-into-table-component)

Can anyone please suggest a better approach for resolving this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want same data source, why are you not just dragging fields from main report itself in detail band,  instead of creating table?

Comment: Because I want it in table format